# Mongo aggregate lookup on array of objects containing id of mutiple collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, lookup

Hi im new to mongo and below  is how my collection named termSet looks now . i have 2 separate collection named termsGroup and terms , to which below ids are referencing to. I want to run lookup and to maintain the array structure as it is. i tried general lookup with unwind , i can get the details at root separately for termGroup and terms , but then loses the array structure and cant find the way to turn the collection back on its original form

```
 "termSet": [
                            {
                                "termGroup": "61879647931c4dd510c206b7",
                                "terms": [
                                    "61860793789a44e0c49c867f",
                                    "61860793789a44e0c49c8680",
                                    "61860793789a44e0c49c8681"
                                ],
                                "_id": "618b43b2435e40567149f5ec"
                            },
                            {
                                "termGroup": "61879647931c4dd510c206b8",
                                "terms": [
                                    "61860793789a44e0c49c8682",
                                    "61860793789a44e0c49c8683"
                                ],
                                "_id": "618b43b2435e40567149f5ed"
                            }
                        ],
```

my current pipeline , collection is too nested

```
  { $unwind: '$location.versions.types.termSet' },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: TermGroup.collection.name,
        localField: 'location.versions.types.termSet.termGroup',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'termGroupData',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Term.collection.name,
        localField: 'location.versions.types.termSet.terms',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'termsData',
      },
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried unwinding `termSet` before lookup, and then re-group afterward?

Comment: yes , but i failed at re grouping termGroup and terms respectively . im at stage where i have termGroup data and terms data in separate array at root of doc

Comment: If you show us that pipeline, we might be able to help fix it.

Comment: i updated the question with current pipeline , i tried re group before but deleted the code after failed attempt

Comment: if full doc with collection is needed , i can provide

Comment: In general, it is best to provide 1 or 2 input docs, the output doc you seek, and your initial attempts to get there.